# How to make date conversion?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I am getting date in string formate ad "2012-04-11T07:51:10+0000" & I want to convert it to NSDate as "11-04-2012". I dont understand how to use "setDateFormat" for this.

This is what I am doing--
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'+'zzzz"];

Please help.

And whatever NSDate I will get I again want to convert to string ie. only 11-04-2012.
I have searched on ggl. But no satisfactory result :(

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to parse the string to generate a date:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-04-11T07:51:10+0000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

Now you can generate a new string representation of the date as follows:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
NSString *newDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"New string: %@", newDateString);
// 11-04-2012
```

---

The problem with the `dateFormat` you were using is that you don't have to escape all the symbols such as `'MM'` and that `zzzz` is not the correct symbol to parse the timezone of type `+0000`.

Have a look at this [documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information.

Comment: But how to get only date part out of this?

Comment: What do you mean? You are probably looking for `newDateString`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Wed, 22 Jun 2011 12:36:00 +0100"; // change value base on your requirement.

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"]; // Change format base on dareStr.
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d YYYY"]; // Change format base on your output requirement
    dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Date -- %@",dateStr);
    [dateFormat release];
```

Comment: This is for get required date from date string.